# Wrong position of Circle of CircleView in view

Tags: ios, swift, view

I have a custom view that draws a circle. I set up my custom view with aspect ratio 1:1 and equal height of 0.5 multiplier to the main view.
My problem is that my circle doesn't set in the center of the view.

[image]

My set up: [image]

The code of CirlceView:

```
class CircleProgress: UIView {
private var trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    setupTrackLayer()
}

func setupTrackLayer() {
    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.width/2 , y: bounds.height/2)


    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: frame.width/2, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 20
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.9450980392, blue: 0.462745098, alpha: 1).cgColor
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: see demo here [CircleView](https://github.com/ShKhan9/CircleView)

```
var Once:Bool = true

override func layoutSubviews()
{
   if(Once)
   {
      setupTrackLayer()
      Once = false
   }

}
```

Or put code in `draw(_ Rect`

Edit: try this , the problem is  using frame , use bounds which is relative to screen

```
   func drawTimeLeftShape() {
    timeLeftShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width / 2.0 , y:  self.bounds.size.height / 2.0), radius:
        min(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2), startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true).cgPath
    timeLeftShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    timeLeftShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    timeLeftShapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
    self.layer.addSublayer(timeLeftShapeLayer)
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand, shall I use your code into mine? I tried it but it gives me an error "Class 'CircleProgress' has no initializers"

Comment: declare bool Once = false

Comment: What does this have to do with the circle not being centered?

Comment: @cesare the demo demonstrates this

Comment: The demo is NOT working when you're using a smaller view, please check https://ufile.io/pu67s

Comment: while the demo does work when the view is the view controller's view.